# How can I create an image on my HTML canvas when I press the space bar in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, javascript-objects

I want to create an image when the space bar is pressed to simulate a bullet firing. The issue is that when I call a draw image function inside JQuery after declaring the image and it's path outside the function, the image doesn't appear on the screen at all. How can I make it so that the bullet is created when the space bar is pressed and continues until it gets off the screen?

```
var bullet = new Image();
bullet.src = "Resources/bullet.png"

$(document).keydown(function(event) {  //jQuery code to recognize a keydown event
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

    if (keycode === 32) {
        //gun facing left
        if (facingleft === true) {

^^^ Don't know how to draw the image when the key is pressed ^^^

            collideFunction()
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
//create a function that allows you to move the bullet with spacebar and 
giving the bullet a direction

    function move(element) {
       element.style.position = 'fixed'

       function moveToCoordinates(left, bottom) {
           element.style.left = left + 'px'
           element.style.bottom = bottom + 'px'
       }

        function moveWithSpaceBar(left, bottom, callback){
            let direction = null;
            let x = left;
            let y = bottom;

            element.style.left = x + 'px'
            element.style.bottom = y + 'px'

            function shootBullet(){
                if(direction === 'east'){
                    x+=1
                }
            }

            setInterval(shootBullet, 1)

            // create event listener for spacebar

            document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
                if(e.key === " "){
                    direction = 'east'
                }
                callback(direction)
            })
            document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
                direction = null
                callback(direction)
            })
        }
        
        return {
            to: moveToCoordinates
            withSpaceBar: moveWithSpaceBar
        }
    }





   //now create your bullet and allow the image to change then move when 
   called 

    function bulletShot(x, y){
        const element = newImage('starting img, perhaps its blank')
        // give it a z index if needed
        element.style.zIndex = 1;

        function bulletDirection(direction){
            if (direction === null){
            element.src = `starting img, perhaps its blank`
            }

            if (direction === 'east'){
            element.src = `bullet img intended to move, perhaps a gif`
            }
        } 

        move(element).withSpaceBar(x, y, bulletDirection)
        return{
            element: element
        }
    }
```

I don't know if this will fix your problem, but maybe someone will find it helpful. It's a way I learned how to move/change images in bootcamp. I am not an expert dev at all, I am actually quite new to JS. So this may or may not work for your specific case. I'd be glad to see someone correct my code. Hope you all have a nice day.